# Split, encode and join video parts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-streaming

It is possible to split file into many parts.Is it possible every part encode and after that join them again? The idea is to encode one video on more computers.
In .NET
Thank you

Comment: You might want to ask an actual question relating to code. Your question only asks if it is possible. Do you want to know how or what libraries can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call ffmpeg.exe from your c# code to accomplish this. There are also some libraries that are available to accomplish this.

Comment: I'd also add that the Handbrake CLI would be useful as well, if you're planning on encoding to formats not supported by Media Foundation. http://handbrake.fr/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DirectShow .NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/index.html) - it has some functionality for video capture and editing, although you still need to be familiar with general processing algorithms and methods.

Answer (score 0):

These two articles can probably point you in the right direction:

**[Stephen Toub's DVR-MS article.](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2007/09/22/fun-with-dvr-ms.aspx)**
Covers reading but also splitting and joining. The splitting and joining stuff can probably be applied to any DirectShow filter, not just DVR-MS files.

**[Managed Encoding with Windows Media Foundation](http://blogs.msdn.com/mf/archive/2010/02/18/mfmanagedencode.aspx)**
Really awesome sample put out by the WMF team. I'd recommend checking out all the other samples they've posted as well, as those cover things like dubbing etc.

Hope this helps!